# WKWebView add button to search field

Tags: javascript, xcode, wkwebview, swift5

I am using `WKWebView` and would like to know if there is a possibility to add a button in an existing search form using `WKWebView` method .evaluateJavaScript and Swift 5. -> screenshot
[image: search form]

Disabling the search button is easy doing:

```
let removeElementScript = "document.querySelector('.main-search--button').style.display='none';"
webView.evaluateJavaScript(removeElementScript)
```

Now I would like to add a new button to open the native camera for scanning barcodes.
The coding for barcode scan is ready and works fine.

Any idea how to add the button?
Here a screenshot from the inspector:
[image: inspector search form]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Now i added the button via coding

```
    var btn = "var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation--list block-group')[0];"
    btn += "var li = document.createElement('li');"
    btn += "li.setAttribute('class', 'navigation--entry entry--scan');"
    btn += "li.setAttribute('role', 'menuitem');"
    btn += "newlink = document.createElement('a');"
    btn += "newlink.setAttribute('class', 'btn');"
    btn += "li.appendChild(newlink);"
    btn += "ul.appendChild(li);"
        
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(btn)
```

Any ideas how to set a image to < li> from Xcode Assets :D.